# How to make ITextSharp ColumnText break only after reaching end of paragraph

Tags: .net, itext, pdf-generation

I'm using ITextSharp to generate PDFs. A few of the texts I'm writing on the PDF are long, and need to be properly wrapped within a set area. I'm using ColumnText for this purpose, and defining a rectangle for the text to be written in.

Below is the code for the same.

```
ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(cb);
ct.SetSimpleColumn(new Rectangle(57, 695, 276, 743));
ct.AddElement(new Paragraph(10.6f, value, FontPR);
ct.Go();
```

Here, cb is a PdfContentByte object, value is a string, while FontPR is a font object I've created. There are no issues if the string is homogenous and the pdf properly prints it upto the end of the rectangle before breaking it. But in case of special characters like '（' or spaces, the line break occurs prematurely. I've tried inserting zero width joiners ('\u200D') between the characters to avoid this, but that didn't seem to help.

Is there a way to avoid premature breaks here?